# Can't figure out how to make this regex pattern

Tags: regex

I need a pattern that matches any set of letters, numbers and underscore bounded by whitespace, `.` or `:`.

Comment: Bounded on both sides?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: @user3851593 Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider bookmarking the [The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496) for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want something like this:

```
^[ .:]\w+[ .:]$
```

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `[ .:]` matches one space char, period or colon
- `\w+` matches one or more letters, digits or underscore
- `[ .:]` matches one space char, period or colon
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

**Potential Tweaks**

- In regex terms, "white-space" does not only mean the space characters, but also tabs, carriage returns and other forms of spacing. If this is what you mean, use `\s` in place of the space inside `[ .:]`
- If you want to allow more than one space character, colon or dot, you can tweak the regex like so: `^[ .:]+\w+[ .:]+$`

Comment: I let my friend try it and he said it didn't work
new.TextureID = Planet:GenerateRandomTexture()
Should yielld
 new TextureId Planet GenerateRandomTexture

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple. This should work:

```
([\s\d][ .:])+[\s\d]+
```

Basically the `[\s\d]` is the letters, numbers or underscores, and the `[ .:]` is the space, dot, or colon.